# Making a word partly italic in org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

When working in Emacs `org-mode`, how do I make a word part italic? I want this:

> word*x*

but when I try `word/x/` it produces

> word/x/

and `word{/x/}` produces

> word{*x*}

Comment: You would probably need to customize `org-emphasis-regexp-components`.

Comment: Your question is almost an exact duplicate of [How to make part of a word bold in `org-mode`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1218238/1199226). The [most recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24540651/1199226) to this question should give you what you need. (In particular, it explains how to customize the `org-emphasis-regexp-components` variable mentioned by @Dan to enable `org-mode` markup for strings that are immediately preceded or followed by one or more letters.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a custom link.

Simple method:

```
(org-add-link-type "emph" nil 'org-export-emph)

(defun org-export-emph (path desc format)
  (let ((text (or desc path)))
    (cond
     ((eql format 'html)
      (format "<em>%s</em>" text))
     ((eql format 'latex)
      (format "\\emph{%s}" text))
     (t
      text))))
```

This then allows you to write par[[emph:ti]]ally em[[emph:ph][ph]]asized words.

Better (?) method:

You only define the link type by

```
(org-add-link-type "emph")
```

and handle that link type via a generic trancoder in your exporter backend.