# Error message from configuring init.el to make part of words bold

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I added this
`setcar org-emphasis-regexp-components " \t('\"{[:alpha:]")`
`(setcar (nthcdr 1 org-emphasis-regexp-components) "[:alpha:]- \t.,:!?;'\")}\\")`
`(org-set-emph-re 'org-emphasis-regexp-components org-emphasis-regexp-components)`
as suggested by **itsjeyd** at 
[How to make part of a word bold in org-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218238/how-to-make-part-of-a-word-bold-in-org-mode) to my init-file
to mark up only a part of a word in `org mode`.

However, I get the following error message:

```
Symbol's value as variable is void: org-emphasis-regexp-components
```

Does someone know a solution to this problem?

Comment: Whenever you get a void something or other, it meas the library containing that something has not been loaded.  Common solutions include, but are not limited to `(require 'library-containing-the-missing-stuff)` before using the stuff that was void, and `eval-after-load` (Google for specific examples).  In this situation, you can grep the org folder to see which library it is, or take a wild guess and just use `(require 'org)` before your stuff that was previously void and see if that works.

Comment: Thank you, I really just had to add `(require 'org)` in my init file.

Comment: Since org is a pretty big (i.e. slow to load) package, I would really look into using `with-eval-after-load` instead of `require`, so you don't load it every time you start Emacs.